# How do I merge several calendar (iCal format) into one in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, date, icalendar

I have several non-overlapping ical files that I want to merge into one ical file.
What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading correct (self)-answer from @knarf and [Format iCalendar files](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45664?hl=en) at support.google.com, I succesfully used this:

```
mergeIcal() {
    sed -e '$d' $1
    sed -e '1,/VEVENT/{/VEVENT/p;d}' $2
}
```

This take whole *first argument file* but not last line (footer) and concatenate *second argument file* without header.

Event duplication will be automatically dropped when loaded by most common *Calendar Agent*.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options (ordered IMHO least useful to most useful for your task):

- If you prefer to use the "standard" DateTime set of modules for datetime manipulation, you can parse in and print calendars using [`DateTime::Format::ICal`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-ICal/) . However, that module parses *iCal* formatted data but not files.
- For purpose of parsing/combining multiple files, you can use [`iCal::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?iCal%3a%3aParser) .  From SYNOPSIS (see line #3 from the botom):

  ```
  use iCal::Parser;
  my $parser=iCal::Parser->new();
  my $hash=$parser->parse($file);
  $parser->parse($another_file);
  my $combined=$parser->calendar;
  ```

  Or

  ```
  use iCal::Parser;
  my $combined=iCal::Parser->new->parse(@files); #### BINGO!!!!!
  ```

  **However, this module doesn't *print* the resulting merged data back into a file**, at least that I know of.
- [`Data::ICal`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-ICal/) set of modules has both parsing and printing, with main module [Data::ICal](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-ICal/) capable of generating a file.

  I wasn't able to find out how to merge the different calendars officially, but it should be fairly trivially to do by looping over second calendar object's `entries` and `properties` (one's an arrayref one is a hash) and using `add_entry()` and `add_property()` of the first calendar object to merge.
- I think you should also be able to convert `ical::Parser` merged data into `Data::ICal`, since the former produces lists of `Text::vFile::asData` objects (with dates replaced by `DateTime` objects); and the latter has `parse_object()` method to parse `Text::vFile::asData` objects.

Comment: The doc doesn't seem to explain how to export/output a complete calendar, I'm not sure it does what I want. Nothing about merging either.

Comment: However, `ical::Parser` doesn't seem to be able to output an iCal file (which, I assume, is what the OP wants to do with the merged data).

Comment: @knarf  - which of the 2 approaches are you talking about?

Comment: @Mich - that's why I added a **bold** text "**this module doesn't print the resulting merged data back into a file**" - and then provided 2 extra bullet points showing how to print.

Comment: @DVK: Right, I made my comment before you added that.

Comment: @DVK, I made my comment before you added all your options.

Comment: Meh. SO doesn't reload the post with comments when you edit. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I ended up concatenate every file without their header/footer and adding header/footer manually.
(I can't accept my own answer whithin 2 days)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going to recommend. The format is a pure text file, and you can simply merge them together into a single file. I wouldn't even have bothered with a script.

Comment: @David W. - That's nice for a one-off. Not for a regular process.

Comment: @DVK: This sounded like a one-off request. I've done something similar recently when my wife's computer broke, she borrowed mine for a few months, then got herself a new one. I had to merge her old address book backup, the one she created on my system, and the one she created on the new computer.

Comment: @David - heh... I'm a developer. I have a natural bias against manual one-off solutions :)